# tkinter making frame sticky with window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to this so not sure where I am going wrong here. I want to make my `Frame_1` stick to the four corners of the window as you drag it out from the bottom right hand corner.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("My Program")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab1.grid(row=0, column=0)

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2.grid(row=0, column=0)

tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

labe1frame_1 = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Frame_1")
labe1frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=NSEW)

txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(labe1frame_1, width=40, height=10)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe if you are using the imported directional variable names you need to use a `+` symbol in between like this `N+S+E+W` however I always just do a string of characters for the sticky like this `"nsew"`. This is better IMO. This is not the actual problem here but wanted to point it out. I think you want to look at `columnconfig()` to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your current GUI set up, using pack throughout may be a better idea:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk


if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("My Program")
    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

    tab1 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    tab2 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    tab_control.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
    tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

    labe1frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(tab1, text="Frame_1")
    labe1frame_1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(labe1frame_1, width=40, height=10)
    txtbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: All good answers here. I ended up changing from grid to pack and found it much easier going.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pack` your `Labeframe` and `scrolledText` with this command to achieve that `pack(expand=True, fil=BOTH)` by removing the `grid` geometry layout manager.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("My Program")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab1.grid(row=0, column=0)

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=E+W+N+S)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

labe1frame_1 = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Frame_1")
labe1frame_1.pack(expand=True, fil=BOTH)

txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(labe1frame_1, width=40, height=10)
txtbox.pack(expand=True, fil=BOTH)

window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow your textbox and Frame 1 to expand by adding a weight to `tab1` and a sticky to `textbox`.

When using grid() you will want to use `columnconfig()` and `rowconfig()` to provide weights to that frame so it can expand with the window resizing.

For the textbox to expand with the frame you will need to add the sticky argument also like this:

```
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
```

See below code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("My Program")

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab1.grid(row=0, column=0)
tab1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # added weight
tab1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # added weight

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2.grid(row=0, column=0)

tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

labe1frame_1 = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Frame_1")
labe1frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nswe")

txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(labe1frame_1, width=40, height=10)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")  # added sticky

window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of a grid column inside a given widget will be equal to the width of its widest cell, and the height of a grid row will be the height of its tallest cell. The sticky attribute on a widget controls only where it will be placed if it doesn't completely fill the cell.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("My Program")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW) #add sticky option

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2.grid(row=0, column=0)

tab_control.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

labe1frame_1 = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Frame_1")
labe1frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=NSEW)


txtbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(labe1frame_1, width=40, height=10)
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW) #add sticky option

window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
labe1frame_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#configure the row and column size of parent window
tab1.columnconfigure(0,weight=3)
tab1.rowconfigure(0,weight=3)

window.mainloop()
```